# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS SENT( 'set')

Tags: javascript, express

I'm receiving this issue "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" but i can't figure  out what is causing it. and when the error does not occur, null values are added to the database.

Here is my code:

```
exports.Create = (modelo, placa, ano) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    connection.query('INSERT INTO cars (modelo, placa, ano) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [modelo, placa, ano],
      (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error)
        }
        resolve(results)
      })
  })
}

exports.Create2 = async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
      modelo,
      placa,
      ano
    } = req.body

    if (!modelo || !placa || !ano) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        Failed: 'field(s) are missing.'
      })
    }

    const results = await create.Create(modelo, placa, ano)
    return res.status(201).json(results)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's related to the error, but you should `return` after `reject(error);`. Otherwise you'll reject and resolve the promise, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Comment: @Barmar FWIW, technically resolve/reject functions are one-shots: once one of a given issued pair has been called, any further calls to either (of the same pair) are ignored and effectively become no-operations. So it's certainly possible, but not necessarily great coding style.